# I need to find out the name and customer id of customers who bought 2 cars from all the 4 dealerships

Tags: mysql

> The sale table include the details of customer id of customers who bought cars from the dealerships represented by the dealer id column in the table. The column vin is the id of car the customer bought.
>
> The dealer table include the id of the dealer and the name of the dealership.The dealer id in dealer table has the same details in the dealer id in sale table.
>
> The customer table includes the id of the customer and the name of the customer.The customer id in the customer table has the same details in the customer id  column in the sale table.
>
> [image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions. Then [edit] your question with your table structure (not as images), the SQL queries you have tried and the (wrong) result you get from them.

Comment: To add to the excellent advice above, readers will generally ask for some prior effort before helping, especially it if it is an academic homework.

Answer (score 2):

As comments indicate, the question should improve. For that reason, here is the code to create the tables with the data.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sale', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.sale;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.customer', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.customer;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.dealer', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.dealer;

CREATE TABLE sale(
SI_no VARCHAR(5),
vin VARCHAR(5),
customer_id VARCHAR(5),
dealer_id VARCHAR(5));

CREATE TABLE customer (
customer_id VARCHAR(5),
cust_name VARCHAR(10));

CREATE TABLE dealer (
dealer_id VARCHAR(5),
dealer_name VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO sale (SI_no,vin,customer_id,dealer_id) VALUES ('01','1v','1c','2d')
INSERT INTO sale (SI_no,vin,customer_id,dealer_id) VALUES ('02','2v','2c','4d')
INSERT INTO sale (SI_no,vin,customer_id,dealer_id) VALUES ('03','3v','1c','4d')
INSERT INTO sale (SI_no,vin,customer_id,dealer_id) VALUES ('04','4v','2c','3d')
INSERT INTO sale (SI_no,vin,customer_id,dealer_id) VALUES ('05','1v','1c','2d')
INSERT INTO sale (SI_no,vin,customer_id,dealer_id) VALUES ('06','2v','1c','4d')
INSERT INTO sale (SI_no,vin,customer_id,dealer_id) VALUES ('07','3v','1c','3d')
INSERT INTO sale (SI_no,vin,customer_id,dealer_id) VALUES ('08','4v','1c','3d')
INSERT INTO sale (SI_no,vin,customer_id,dealer_id) VALUES ('09','1v','2c','3d')
INSERT INTO sale (SI_no,vin,customer_id,dealer_id) VALUES ('10','3v','1c','1d')
INSERT INTO sale (SI_no,vin,customer_id,dealer_id) VALUES ('11','4v','1c','1d');

INSERT INTO customer (customer_id,cust_name) VALUES ('1c','hari')
INSERT INTO customer (customer_id,cust_name) VALUES ('2c','sam');

INSERT INTO dealer (dealer_id,dealer_name) VALUES ('1d','Honda')
INSERT INTO dealer (dealer_id,dealer_name) VALUES ('2d','Toyota')
INSERT INTO dealer (dealer_id,dealer_name) VALUES ('3d','Hyundai')
INSERT INTO dealer (dealer_id,dealer_name) VALUES ('4d','Ferrari');
```

The answer to your question is to pivot the table to the different dealers as your column names along with the values that the customer has bought. Then, you perform a join to bring the information which you need. You should perform a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT A.[customer_id],c.[cust_name]
FROM (
SELECT [customer_id],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [dealer_id] = '1d' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Honda,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [dealer_id] = '2d' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Toyota,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [dealer_id] = '3d' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Hyundai,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [dealer_id] = '4d' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ferrari
FROM [sale]
GROUP BY [customer_id])A
JOIN [customer] AS c
ON A.[customer_id]=c.[customer_id]
WHERE  A.Honda>0 AND A.Toyota>0 AND A.Hyundai>0 AND A.Ferrari>0
```